# Why does my pilot light go out continuously?

Tags: furnace

My furnace pilot light keeps going out.  The furnace will come on and heat up to the degree set on my thermostat, then the pilot goes out and the furnace will not come back on. Could the thermostat be bad and cause the pilot light to go out? Is there anyway for me to check the problem myself?